# Cannot access protected member declared in class 'A'

Tags: c++, oop

This is a piece of code I found in an example in one of my OOP courses. When I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
'A::x' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'A'.
```

Because of inheritance, shouldn't B be able to access A's protected int?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
protected: int x;
public: A(int i = -16) { x = i; }
        virtual A f(A a) { return x + a.x; }
        void afisare() { cout << x; }
};

class B : public A
{
public: B(int i = 3) :A(i) {}
        A f(A a) { return x + a.x + 1; }
};

int main()
{
    A *p1 = new B, *p2 = new A, *p3 = new A(p1->f(*p2));
    p3->afisare();
    system("Pause");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`B` can access `A`'s member `x` but only the one it inherits. It cannot access member `x` of another instance of `A` (`a.x` in `f`).